# How to spend P2WSH address with full redem script and witness program?

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions, p2sh, p2pkh, p2wsh

I just put few dollar in here.

Bech32 Address: `bc1qx6c07u2s6pu6d5ede8ee9hmynahp9edgg764cm58gfxmryk3ryqsxarnnv`

Witness Script Hex `76a914b1217062623d9101426f61593cb1abc3e44ed00488ac`

Witness Script Asm
`OP_DUP OP_HASH160 14<b1217062623d9101426f61593cb1abc3e44ed004> OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG`

Witness Version 0

Witness Program `36b0ff7150d079a6d32dc9f392df649f6e12e5a847b55c6e87424db192d11901`

ScriptPubKey Hex    `002036b0ff7150d079a6d32dc9f392df649f6e12e5a847b55c6e87424db192d11901`

ScriptPubKey Asm `OP_0 20<36b0ff7150d079a6d32dc9f392df649f6e12e5a847b55c6e87424db192d11901>`

show me how to spend this, feel free if you want to just take the fund of it, i do this for educational for security building P2WSH address from P2SH redemscript hash160.

Comment: That is not P2TR as it as a witness version of 0. P2TR is witness version 1. It appears to be a P2PKH nested inside of a P2WSH.

Comment: Perhaps this sort of testing would be better directed at Testnet or Signet?

Comment: sorry, i was missspell the type of Addresses, yes it's P2PKH nested inside of a P2WSH

Comment: i make the address for mainnet.